# Am I correctly testing that methods from Kernel have been called?

Tags: ruby

Any time I'm testing a Ruby class that calls a Kernel method such as `sleep` or `exit`, i define a singleton method on the class instance and test that it has been invoked:

```
it "must throttle requests" do
  sleep_was_called = false

  subject.define_singleton_method(:sleep) { |seconds|
    sleep_was_called = true
  }

  subject.request query
  subject.request query

  sleep_was_called.must_equal true
end
```

I have seen far more sophisticated method stub testing in RSpec, but it there a more fancy and less verbose way to do this using MiniTest?

Comment: This seems like more of an SO type question.

Answer (score 3):

I know MiniTest has an expectations framework, but I'm not familiar with it.  I use rspec-expectations to accomplish this, like so:

```
describe ClassName do
  let(:subject) { described_class.new }

  describe '#method' do
    it 'should sleep 3 times and output hello world' do
      expect(subject).to receive(:sleep).exactly(3).times
      expect(subject).to receive(:puts).with('Hello world!').exactly(3).times

      subject.method
    end
  end
end
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but my hope is it leads you in the right direction.

Comment: However, it's not a great idea to do this much. It's normally better to test behavior, not implementation, except in a few special cases.